# ListView IllegalStateException in an array[]-based adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have an adapter, it is a nested class:

```
protected abstract class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private Data[] data;

    protected MyAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setData(Data[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data == null || data.length == 0 ? 0 : data.length * 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return data == null ? null : data[i / 2];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
    }
         ///other methods not modifying data[]
}
```

I use setData(Data[] data) only in one place:

```
public void setNewData(Data[] data) {
    if (!Arrays.deepEquals(myAdapter.data, data)) {
        myAdapter.setData(data);
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    updateVisibility();
}
```

And access to the variable in one place:

```
protected void updateVisibility() {
    Data[] localData = myAdapter.data;

    if (localData != null && localData.length > 0) {
        //do smth not related to localData[]
    } 
}
```

In google play I see that users get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131427598, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter]
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1544)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:4141)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7350)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2464)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
```

But can't understand from where it comes.

ADDED:

I think that here is the reason:

In a child class I override the getCount() method and it returns different numbers based on the orientation.

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int count = super.getCount();

        if (isPortrait(context.getResources())) {
            count++;  
        }

        return count;
    }
```

I think that I should update the listView's cached item count somewhere here.
What do you think? Am I right?

Comment: when you update your adapter add a line `notifydatasetchanged(adapter);` its happening because data in your adapter has been modified but not notified

Comment: as you can see I call notifydatasetchanged() after setting data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you dont use `data` array that comes to `setNewData` anywhere else? Maybe you reuse this array and update it somehow? This exception is thrown in case when internal listView's item count not equals adapter's `getCount` when listView layout it's items. Recheck your code.

Comment: Good comment, I checked it. Could you please take a look at my editions?

Comment: Yeah. This might be a problem. If adapter's data gets changed somehow you should call notifydatasetchanged. And it is a really bad idea to check orientation iside adapter. You better create 2 versions of your adapter and swap between them when orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling setNewData?

If you are calling it after the adapter has been initialized, call

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()